# `[]': Can't convert String into Integer (TypeError) Ruby script

Tags: ruby, json, typeerror

I'm writing a simple function in a ruby script to get the ID attribute from some JSON data.

```rb
def getObjectTypeId()
    objects = post(@server.oS.getAllTypeObjectCounts())
    myObject = objects.find_all{|xObjectCountInfo| xObjectCountInfo['ObjectInfo']['ObjectTypeID'] == 'myObjectTypeID'}
    puts myObject
    @objectTypeId = myObject['ObjectInfo']['ID']
end
```

The error is happening on the final line of the function. As you can see, I'm printing `myObject` to the console to verify that it's a hash and not an array (which is the most common issue I've seen that causes this error).  Here's a snippet of the output:

```
{"_class"=>"XObjectCountInfo", "ObjectInfo"=>{"_class"=>"XObjectInfo", "ID"=>"10102", "ObjectTypeID"=>"myObjectTypeID"}}
```

What could be causing me to get the "can't convert String to Integer" type error?

Comment: Please use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` when naming functions an variables in Ruby. This is the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Enumerable#find_all`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) gives an array when used with block. Your `myObject` is an array of size 1, I am quite sure. You used `puts` method to print it, so you are seeing the only one element hash of the array. Use `p myObject`, you will get to see that the object `myObject` is an one element array. Your  modified last statement `@objectTypeId = myObject['ObjectInfo']['ID']`, will be `@objectTypeId = myObject.map{|h| h['ObjectInfo']['ID'] }`

I used [`Enumerable#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) as, `#find_all` returns an array of collection. This time you have only one element in the array,but any time you can have more than one element. In this case `#map` would be a good choice I think.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is really raised on the last line of the method you provided, either `myObject` or my `myObject['ObjectInfo']` is an array not a hash.

I'm suspecting the `myObject` as it is returned by `find_all`